# "There was no endpoint listening at" - depending on connecting client

Tags: asp.net, iis, server, configuration

I have some websites that should be able to get data from each other by a webservice.
Every website is using the "same" code so in every website(s) web.config, you have both the service and client config.
When doing a request, url is set in runtime like:

```
foreach(var sibling in mySiblings)
{
  var client = new MySoapClient("MySoapClient", sibling.Host + "/webservice/MySoapClient.asmx");
  var info = client.GetInfo();
  allInfo.Add(info);
}
```

(only pseudo code)

All sites are hosted on the same server.
When code is executed, you get an error after a while:
"There was no endpoint listening at 'http://host_address/webservice/MySoapClient.asmx' that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details."

InnerException: "Unable to connect to the remote server"

Adding log to the code above, checking the "client.EndPoint.ListenUri.AbsoluteUri" gives you a correct path, that can be reached when entered in a browser.

Now, the real annoying problem:
There are some servers/sites that CAN connect - and some that can't.

There is another server, with "same" sites - only this is the test-sites.
(Copy of the code, copy of the databases - other dns-names)

The test-sites can connect to the other test-sites webservices and get data.
The test-sites can NOT connect to Prod-sites

The prod-sites can connect to sites on the test-server.
The prod-sites can NOT connect to Prod-sites. (Not even to it self)

So, it seems like there is a problem with the prod-sites/server.
Only problem with that...if you set it up on you local machine - you can get data from both test - and prod.

I also built a simple test-client, (aspx-page) containing a dropdownlist with hostnames, For prod and for test. And a button.
Click the button: Make a call to a simple method in the webservice of selected host.
I then set this up in the IIS as "http://public-ip-number/wsTest" on four locations.

Running this on my own computer: Can connect to both test and prod.
Running this on the test-server: Can connect to test.
Running this on the prod-server: Can connect to test.
Running this on a third server I have access to: Can connect to both test and prod.

Test and Prod are hosted by a hosting company. Both servers has been setup the exact same way, since test should reflect prod. (Windows 2016 server) Or at least they should.
My system: Windows 10
The third server: Windows Server 2012.

Since the code is identical on the two servers, I don't think that's the problem. Specially since everything works when calls are done "from the outside".

I have access to the servers through VPN/RDS, and have full administrator roles. But there is no visual difference on how the servers are set up, as far as I can see.

Could there be some firewall blocking on the hosting-part?

I really don't know where to look! 
Anyone with any ideas...I'm all ears!

Comment: What sort of authentication are you using? Are the 'bad' requests actually getting through to the server (try looking in the IIS log files to see if the requests are making it through)? If they aren't, it would be more of a pure networking issue than a web services-type issue

Answer (score 0):

Update:
This wasn't actually a coding-problem.

The hosting-company had indeed added a rule to the firewall, "The problem is NAT Loopback. This means that the server shall access itself on public IP addresses."

After they fixed it, everything worked as it should.